# Display order for multiple installed SpFx Extensions bottom Placeholder

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-extensions

I have 2 seperate extensions which are rendered in the bottom placeholder. Both the solutions are different and are activated.

Extension 1 : Having footer details which is more of rendering of static text in a customised format.

Extension 2: displays a feedback form and then inserts in the custom list using graph API. There are functionality like populating user details etc in this.

Ideally, I want Extension 2 to be displayed first and then Extension 1 in the footer.

However, random display order is observed sometimes. ie footer is displayed first and then the custom form. On page refresh, the rendering is normal.

I did search and came across similar question https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/885 but it does not have any solution.

Question is what is setting the precedence of the display order of the extensions in the same bottom placeholder ?

Answer (score 1):

- You are supposed to be able to control the order of when the app customizers are loaded on the page using the sequence attribute on the `<CustomAction>` element.
- Refer this article for more details.

  [Custom Action](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/customaction-element)
- Similar thread on GitHub

  [application customizer placeholder top sort order](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/3459#issuecomment-464772528)